# haw i can parse CGPDFArrayRef with CGPDF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, iostream

please i have a question, i try to parse my pdf file and i can find  the key and the value but my problem that i want show the value of kids haw i can do? i can only show the count of table

```
  case kCGPDFObjectTypeArray: {
            CGPDFArrayRef value  = NULL;

            CGPDFDictionaryRef contentDict = (CGPDFDictionaryRef)info;
            CGPDFDictionaryGetArray(contentDict, key, &value);
            NSLog(@"pdf array is %lu",CGPDFArrayGetCount(value));


             CGPDFArrayRef objectArray;
             if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, kCGPDFObjectTypeArray, &objectArray)) 
             {



             NSLog(@"pdf array value: %zu", CGPDFArrayGetCount(objectArray)); 


             }
        }



3 0 obj
<<
 /Type /Pages
 /Kids [4 0 R]
 /Count 1
>>
endobj
```

Comment: no help please i need find solution